# C# - Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект

Tags: c#

Начал создание библиотеки классов на C#. Одна из первых её целей - проверить первое поле базы данных. Подключил базу данных MS Acess - TempTaskDB (источник данных - TempTasksData). Дальше ввёл чтение поля и его проверки на пустоту. Но появляется ошибка: "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "TempTasksData" требуется ссылка на объект. Как использовать ссылку или исправить данную ошибку?
Вот часть кода:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MethodsLibrary
{
    public class LibraryClass
    {
        public void Synchronization(string server)
        {
            try
            {
                Int32 port = 9595;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
                string msg = "sync";
                if (TempTasksData.taskData[0].Task != null) // ОШИБКА
                {
                    //...
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что есть TempTasksData ?

Comment: Добавте также фрагмент кода, где вы определили `TempTasksData`.

Comment: навскидку могу сказать, что внутри TempTasksData определены обычные филды / проперти. Если хотите использовать так, как написали в блоке try, сделайте их статиками, в противном случае - создайте инстанс TempTasksData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к TempTasksData.taskData как к статическому свойству, хотя оно таковым не является. Тут два выхода

1. Сделать TempTasksData.taskData статическим в определении типа

   class TempTaskData
   {
     public **static** Task[] taskData;
   }
2. Создать объект типа TempTasksData и обращаться к его свойству

   var tempTask = new TempTasksData();
    if (tempTask.taskData[0].Task != null)